# Removing Non-Duplicated Items from List (python)

Tags: python, for-loop

I have this list:

```
mylist = [['TX', 'DALLAS'],
 ['TX', 'DALLAS'],
 ['CA', 'LA'],
 ['CA', 'LA'],
 ['ID', 'BOISE']],
```

I've been trying to write a loop that makes a new list containing only those that were duplicates.

This is my current code:

```
for i in mylist:
  if mylist.count(i) > 1:
    mylist.remove(i)

mylist
```

my output:

```
[['TX', 'DALLAS'], ['CA', 'LA'], ['ID', 'BOISE']]
```

So the output would be:

```
[['TX', 'DALLAS'], ['CA', 'LA']],
```

Comment: "I've been trying to write a loop" Okay. What code did you write? What happened when you tried using that code? What specific problem did you encounter? What is your *question* about that problem? Please read [ask].

Comment: Make a list containing all the elements and their counts. Then filter that to just the ones where the count > 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
list_of_lists = [['TX', 'DALLAS'],
                 ['TX', 'DALLAS'],
                 ['CA', 'LA'],
                 ['CA', 'LA'],
                 ['ID', 'BOISE']]

duplicates = []

for item in list_of_lists:
    if list_of_lists.count(item) > 1 and item not in duplicates:
        duplicates.append(item)

print(duplicates)
```